# youtrack workflow get comment author

Tags: workflow, youtrack

```
    // --- #1 issueCommentIsAdded ---
    const issue_0 = ctx.issue;

    const issueCommentIsAddedFn_0 = () => {
    const if_added_by = issue_0.comments.added.isNotEmpty() && issue_0.comments......... == "autobot" 
      return if_added_by 
    };
```

I need to check if the comment was from a specific user. then perform some action

Comment: If you use GIT then each change made to a file also has a ghost note next to it, on most IDE, that indicates who made it

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I used the default workflow constructor in youtrack

Comment: comments.added.last.author.login
is not working in last version
got error: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
issue_0.comments.last().author.login
```

is working.